# <cite> & <strong> elements

Tags: html, markup

Is that correct to use `<strong>` if you've already placed the word inside `<cite>` and want to pay search engines more attention to this? So that word that you usually makes **strong** but this time this also **cite**. How to mark up it correct then?

And the additional question what's more correct

```
<strong><cite>word</cite></strong>
```

or

```
<cite><strong>word</strong></cite>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither one is invalid but I would go with your first option:

```
<strong><cite>word</cite></strong>
```

This usage ties  more closely to the word(s) and it allows the strong to emphasize the importance of the citation rather than just the word(s) in the citation.

usage documentation:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element

usage documentation:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element

Answer (score 2):

Both ways of nesting `cite` and `strong` are syntactically correct. The difference between them is highly theoretical and hardly relevant, though it may impact styling (e.g., if you set color on both `cite` and `strong`).

But to address the theoretical question: `<strong><cite>word</cite></strong>` means strong emphasis on “word” as a title of a work (e.g., a book), whereas `<cite><strong>word</strong></cite>` means that “word” as strongly emphasized expression is the title of a work – so that the emphasis would be in the title itself. The first alternative sounds thus more logical.

Either way, it will hardly have impact on search engines. Some search engines may treat the rest of the document as slightly less important. (Or, to put it inanother way, they may assign a slightly larger *relative* weight to the content of a `strong` element, relative to the content of the page in general.)